# sqlite not auto incrementing

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

When I use the following command to create my table in SQLite3 it does not auto increment ID nor does it make USERNAME a primary key as I can enter multiple users with the same USERNAME and it will input them without issues.

Command:

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
    'id' INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT, 
    'username' TEXT NOT NULL, 
    'hash' TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id', 'username')
);
```

Here is an output from a console to show what it is doing, as you can tell it let me enter the username cat twice and did not assign a value to id as it should have according to auto increment:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE 'users' ('id' INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT, 'username' TEXT NOT NULL, 'hash' TEXT, PRIMARY KEY ('id', 'username'));

sqlite> insert into users (username, hash) values ('cat', 'dog2');

sqlite> insert into users (username, hash) values ('cat', 'dog2');

sqlite> select * from users;                                                                                                                                     
id          username    hash      
----------  ----------  ----------

            cat         dog2      
            cat         dog2
```

Comment: I'm not sure how sqlite handles auto incrementing, but `PRIMARY KEY(id, username)` should mean exactly that, id AND username TOGETHER make the PK; if you want username to be unique, you need a separate UNIQUE constraint/key on just that field.

Answer (score 1):

It's `AUTOINCREMENT`, not `AUTO INCREMENT`. Also, if the field in the SQLite table has the `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute, it should be also `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, hash TEXT);
```

You can't use the field with `AUTOINCREMENT` attribute as a part of compound key.